# Upload image with loopj android to slim framework based REST api?

Tags: android, image-uploading, slim

I am trying to upload image using Params.

Android code:

POST Data to Server

```
 RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
            params.put("item_name", "Name of item");
            params.put("item_image", encodedImage);

            MyRestClient.post(MainActivity.this, "item",params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {

                    JSONArray jArr = response;

                    super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {

                    String responseFromAPI = responseString;

                    super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseString, throwable);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {

                    String responseStr = responseString;

                    super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, responseString);
                }


                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {

                    JSONObject jObj = response;

                    super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {

                    JSONObject jOBj = errorResponse;

                    super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONArray errorResponse) {
                    JSONArray jArr = errorResponse;

                    super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
                }
            });
```

Bitmap Image Encode

```
  public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
            String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

            return encodedImage;

        }
```

Slim Framework Code:

```
    $app->post('/image', function ($request, $response) {


    $input          =   $request->getParsedBody();

    $uploaded_image =   $input['image_image'];    

    $path           =   "/..../uploads/"."img-".date("Y-m-d-H-m-s").".jpg";

    if (file_put_contents($path, base64_decode($uploaded_image)) != false)
    {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO item (item_name, item_image) VALUES (:restaurant_name, :restaurant_image)";

        $sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindParam("item_name", $input['item_name']);    
        $sth->bindParam("item_image", $input['item_image']); 

        $sth->execute();

        $input['id'] = $this->db->lastInsertId();

    }


    return $this->response->withJson($input);
});
```

Problem:

The photo should be uploaded as per the code and my understanding. It is not uploading the image to the desired folder.

Am I doing things correctly or have I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$app->post('/image', function ($request, $response) {

    $files = $request->getUploadedFiles();
    $file = $files['image_image']; // uploaded file

    $parameters = $request->getParams(); // Other POST params

    $path = "/..../uploads/"."img-".date("Y-m-d-H-m-s").".jpg";

    if ($file->getError() === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

        $file->moveTo($path); // Save file

        // DB interactions here...

        $sql = "INSERT INTO item (item_name, item_image) VALUES (:restaurant_name, :restaurant_image)";

        $sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindParam("item_name", $input['item_name']);    
        $sth->bindParam("item_image", $input['item_image']); 

        // if statement is executed successfully, return id of the last inserted restaraunt
        if ($sth->execute()) {

            return $response->withJson($this->db->lastInsertId());

        } else {

            // else throw exception - Slim will return 500 error
            throw new \Exception('Failed to persist restaraunt');

        }

    } else {

        throw new \Exception('File upload error');

    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you. Just wanted to inform that the image will be posted along with other fields. It is a form with an image option. In that case, will I write $request->getUploadedFiles(); ?

Comment: To access other request params you can use `$request->geteParams()` (like access `$_POST`).
Treat `$request->getUploadedFiles()` as access to `$_FILES`.

Comment: I want to update my UI after getting either Success or failure in the above code in the Android code (client post code)? Can I keep a flag variable or is there some other way?

Comment: Thank you. I have another question. I am storing the item as json string in sqlite. I want to POST this JSON on server. Now in order to post, I will convert the JSON to Object. Then will make it in a List<T>. The thing is each object of my item contains image that I wish to upload during POST to server. How can I achieve this functionality? I tried but couldn't find a way to do it. One way in my mind is to store local path of image and then make multiple POST requests (one for each record) to send the data.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't really get the idea from the comment. Could you post it as a new question?

Comment: Sure. Let me do that.

Comment: Actually I am not sure if my question will be entertained and the moderators might make it duplicate to this one.

Comment: In the current code I am sending one image per POST request. I want to send multiple images that will be in an object. Say I have an object ITEM. That object will be a list like List<ITEM>. That list of Items will be POST via JSON. Now each ITEM will have an image just like I showed it in my original question. Instead of sending one JSON object, now I want to send array of JSON objects to PHP REST API. Each object will have an image in it as well.

Comment: I have added a question with specifc details about my current scenario and challanges. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542834/how-to-post-list-of-objects-as-json-from-android-client-to-php-rest-api

Comment: I have another question @Georgy Ivanov. Is there a possibility I can upload the images one by one using loopj?

Comment: @Abubaker, I wish I could help, but I have no idea - I'm a PHP developer.